# Getting a list of the items in "Fields & Relationships" under Object Manager

Tags: fields, object

I thought that this should be fairly straightforward, but I'm not finding a way to do it. If I go to Object Manager, then Account, and then Fields & Relationships - I need a way to get a csv of all the items that are there. Is there perhaps a SOQL query that will do this?

Comment: You can use a schema or metadata tool like [Cloud Toolkit](https://cloudtoolkit.co) and also search the AppExchange for tools like Config Workbook.

Comment: Also FYI CCI's https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html#generate-data-dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can SOQL for this information as follows:

```
SELECT Label, QualifiedApiName FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
```

To get a CSV file there are several tools you can use. I like the [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh) Chrome Extension. But you can also use Salesforce's Data Loader.

If you need any other information about the fields (e.g. data type, length) you can use the fields for `FieldDefinition` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm).

Comment: Hi @Fred this worked out really great - is there also a way to include the "SortData Type" column in the query?

Comment: @lengthy_preamble sorry could you explain what "sortdata type" is?

Comment: Apologies, I found out it was just "data type" - I was able to figure it out, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFDX CLI to get this sort of information in JSON and use your preferred way to convert that into a CSV. I have used "jq", for working with JSON data in the command-line environment to get a sample extract of name, type and relationship name using the below command.

```
sfdx force:schema:sobject:describe --sobjecttype "SObjNAME" --json | jq -r '.result.fields[] | [.name, .type, .relationshipName?] | @csv' > custom_object_fields.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to get **Salesforce DevTools** chrome extension

1. Navigate to Chrome webstore and install the extension
   [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-devtools/ehgmhinnhggigkogkbhnbodhbfjgncjf?hl=en]

2.Login to your SF instance and open the extension.

3.Open a record on the object where you want to export fields

4.Click active button on popup and complete the Auth.

5.Click export and use 2nd option to export the fields of the object.
[image: Export object fields from chrome extension]