# How to get the length of all the fields in an object

Tags: apex, soql, metadata, fields

I'm looking for a way to get the max length of each field in an object. I believe if I do something like

```
System.Debug(ObjectName.FieldName.getDescribe().length);
```

In Apex, it will get me the length of a single field. I would like to get a bulk result that I can put in a CSV or something, hopefully without having to write a python script to do it.

The idea is that we're pulling data from Salesforce into Oracle using an ETL application, and the Oracle developer wants to make sure each column has appropriate character limitations. Is there possibly a SOQL query or Apex code that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a SOQL query for this. It will be the same query as for your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/407591/getting-a-list-of-the-items-in-fields-relationships-under-object-manager). Just add `Length` to the fields you are querying:

```
SELECT Label, QualifiedApiName, Length FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
```

Then you can extract a CSV of the data using Data Loader or another tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in a loop. It's really not that difficult. Here's an example in Apex:

```
String[] csvRows = new String[] { 'Field API Name,Type,Length' };
for(sObjectField field: sObjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values()) {
    DescribeFieldResult result = field.getDescribe();
    csvRows.add(result.getName()+','+result.getType()+','+result.getByteLength());
}
System.debug(String.join(csvRows,'\n'));
```